# How to get correct Angle using python

Tags: python

I am try to find the angle of line

i know the coordinate points

Start Point : 404, 119
Mid Point   : 279, 214
End Point   : 154, 310

```py
import numpy as np

def findangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
    ria = np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) - np.arctan2(y3 - y1, x3 - x1)
    webangle = int(np.abs(ria * 180 / np.pi))
    return webangle
```

result

[image: my output]

Its return 270. But actual angle is 85-90.

Now, I want formula to calculate the angle (Either i Will rotate the image clockwise or Anticlockwise that time also return actual angle) in python code

Comment: Please explain what you think is wrong with your current code

Comment: What is "perfect formula"? What is "angle at 360' degree rotation"? And why your current solution is flawed?

Comment: i think it can calculate outside of figure 360-270=90.  i hope you get it

Comment: assuming that you are satisfied with your calculation, then `webangle_new` = 360 - `webangle`.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result. With the current description, we cannot reproduce the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Ok i will check

Comment: NO,its not work i rotate the image after its result -272

Comment: Now it's clear. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple math. The `numpy.arctan2()` returns a value in the range [-π, π]. So a difference of two values is in the range [-2π, 2π], and the absolute value of that is in the range [0, 2π]. You want an angle *x* in the range [0, π], and *x* is equivalent to (2π - *x*) in your context. So you can take *x* if *x* < π, and take (2π - *x*) otherwise.

So, just do like this using `min()` for example.

```
def findangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
    ...
    return min(webangle, 360 - webangle)
```

As a side note, you don't need to use Numpy functions for a scalar input. Just use the `math.atan2()` and `math.fabs()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to adjust the returned angle based on the range you wish the result to be in.

The following assumes you desire results between -180 (inclusive) and 180 (exclusive).

```py
def adjust(a, degrees=True):
    v = 180 if degrees else np.pi
    return (a + v) % (2 * v) - v

def angle(p, degrees=True):
    assert p.shape == (3, 2), 'p should have 3 points, in 2D'
    yx = p[:, ::-1]
    a0 = np.arctan2(*(yx[1] - yx[0]))
    a1 = np.arctan2(*(yx[2] - yx[1]))
    a = np.rad2deg(a1 - a0) if degrees else a1 - a0
    return adjust(a, degrees)
```

And here is some code to test validity:

```py
def rot(a, degrees=True):
    a = np.deg2rad(a) if degrees else a
    sa, ca = np.sin(a), np.cos(a)
    return np.array([[ca, sa], [-sa, ca]])

def genp(angle, initial=0, lengths=(1, 1), degrees=True):
    p0 = np.array((0, 0))
    p1 = np.array((lengths[0], 0))
    p2 = p1 + np.array((lengths[1], 0)) @ rot(angle, degrees=degrees)
    p = np.vstack((p0, p1, p2)) @ rot(initial, degrees=degrees)
    return p

def plot_problem(p, ax=None):
    ax = plt.gca() if ax is None else ax
    ax.plot(*p.T, '-o')
    for s, xy in zip(list('abc'), p):
        ax.annotate(s, xy, xytext=(0, 5), textcoords='offset points')
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

Example:

```py
p = genp(60, initial=30, lengths=(2, 1))
>>> angle(p)
60.0

plot_problem(p)
```

[image]

Now, a stress test:

```py
n = 1000
np.random.seed(0)
for _ in range(n):
    a = np.random.uniform(-180, 180)
    initial = np.random.uniform(-180, 180)
    lengths = np.random.uniform(1, 10, size=2)
    p = genp(a, initial, lengths)
    ahat = angle(p)
    assert np.allclose(a, ahat)
```

Which passes.